# Getting substrings of the !today variable in Fitnesse

Tags: fitnesse

I'm writing a Fitnesse test for a web application. One of the items to test is a drop-down box, whose value is determined by the current date, in DD/MM/YYYY format.

I'd thought that using the !today variable in the Fitnesse suite might be a useful way of setting a variable, but I've run into the problem that Fitnesse expresses the date as (for example) *11 Mar, 2011*, where I need *11/03/2011*. I can get the date in numberic format using the `-xml` modifier, but I'm still left with a pretty huge string like *2011-03-11T05:51:22*.

Is there a way of getting substrings of this, and then piping those into page variables, or am I barking up entirely the wrong tree here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!today (MM/dd/yyyy)` produces `09/17/2012`. You can use any format codes you like. It uses the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out not *entirely* the wrong tree :-)

For reference, the !today function has a few other methods, and you can use them to gather individual sections of the date as necessary:

!today (dd) - gives the day of the month, in numeric form
!today (MM) - gives the month of the year, in numeric form
!today (yyyy) - gives the year, in numeric form

There are a few others, but all I ended up using were these. Combine them as necessary, and Robert is your mother's brother, as it were...

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the date you require in Test Cases written in Fitnesse Wiki

${=!today (ddMMyyyy)=}

Answer (score 1):

The ! (Exclamation mark) is interpreted literally, so symbols like `!today` are not expanded. You can use a plain table:

```
|class name|
|!today (MM/dd/yyyy)|
```